# Refresh UI after confirmation button in a Blazored Modal popup - Blazor Client

Tags: modal-dialog, blazor, client, webassembly, blazored

I have a method on my page which calls a DeleteApplication.razor component and passes in the selected application:

```
private void deleteApplicationSubmit() 
    {
        var parameters = new ModalParameters
        {
            { nameof(DeleteApplication.applicationData), applicationData }
        };

        Modal.Show<DeleteApplication>("Are you sure you would like to delete", parameters);
    }
```

This opens the DeleteApplication popup.  When clicking the Confirm/Delete button, the Delete method closes the popup and calls the deleteApplication method on my original screen (APIShapes):

```
@code {

    [CascadingParameter] BlazoredModalInstance BlazoredModal { get; set; } = default!;

    [Parameter] public ApiApplication? applicationData { get; set; }

    private APIShapes? apiShapes;

    async Task Delete()
    {
        await apiShapes.deleteApplication(applicationData);

        await BlazoredModal.CloseAsync();
    }

    async Task Cancel() => await BlazoredModal.CancelAsync();
}
```

The deleteApplication method then calls the api to delete the selected application.

I would expect calling the api to delete the selected item would update the UI and remove the item.  Instead, the item remains until I click to load a different screen or when doing a refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `deleteApplicationSubmit()` in the parent component it opens the dialog and runs to completion.  There's no await on the modal.Result task.

When you click on `Delete` in the model - which is a sub component - it runs runs the delete against `apiShapes`, closes the dialog and runs to completion.  It only renders the sub-component.  A component render doesn't cascade a render up the render tree only down.

You need to await the closure of the modal dialog in `deleteApplicationSubmit` like this:

```cs
// Note method is now async and returns a task
private async Task deleteApplicationSubmit() 
    {
        var parameters = new ModalParameters
        {
            { nameof(DeleteApplication.applicationData), applicationData }
        };

        var modal = Modal.Show<DeleteApplication>("Are you sure you would like to delete", parameters);
        
        // now await the modal closing
        var result = await modal.Result;

        // only runs after completion
        if (result.Cancelled)
        {
            // Do whatever
        }
        else if (result.Confirmed)
        {
            // do what you need to do to update the data that will be displayed
            // if this method is called from a UI event the component will re-render automatically
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works great!  Thanks for the help on this.  Still very new to blazor and couldn't figure out why this wouldn't update.